# How to serialize NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I'm exploring server side JavaScript with NodeJS and writing REST APIs with ExpressJS.  My REST API is for configuring a device, much like configuring your home router.  I would like to prevent parallel REST calls from attempting to configure the client without preventing multiple non-config requests.

Example API resources:

```
/api/config/network
/api/config/filesystem
```

In my example API, conceptually I'd like one client to be able to configure the network resource while another client configures the file system resource, while allowing other clients to query those resources.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this with JavaScripts asynchronous programming model.  I come from a non-asynchronous programming background (multi-threaded C++).  I am having trouble wrapping my head around this problem and wondering what ways one can solve this problem by hand, what if I had to write the plugin/module?.

Comment: There are libraries to help you handle that, such as https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: Have you attempted anything on this yet? It usually much easier to help someone when they've posted some code that shows what they've attempted already.

Comment: @tkone my issue is I'm not sure what to attempt.

Comment: @bfavaretto thanks I'll look at that library, though I'm more interested in how I might accomplish it myself.

Comment: You could take a look at http://npmjs.org/package/generic-pool as well

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do, so it's difficult to give you any specific advice. Could you add more details?

Comment: @bfavaretto suppose I wanted to serialize the response to call to rest resources without using the async.js lib.  Assume that for configuration I'll exec() some script.  I don't want multiple clients calling that script and I don't want to have to add protection against multiple clients in that script.

Comment: Looks like you're dealing with two levels of async here, one being async calls within a single request, and the other being multiple concurrent requests. I'll let Peter Lyons answer that, as my experience with node is very limited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When your express app gets a request to edit the config, add an item to an [async.js queue](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#queue) configured with concurrency of 1. This will prevent > 1 concurrent attempt to edit the remote configuration. Pseudo code would be:

- at app startup, define your `updateNetworkConfig` function
- at app startup, create a queue of concurrency 1

  - `var networkQueue = async.queue(updateNetworkConfig, 1);`
- REST comes in like PUT /api/config/network with the new config as the request body in JSON
- Add an item to the queue, passing along the new config data

  - `networkQueue.push(req.body.config);`
  - (`req.body` provided by the bodyParser connect middleware)
- Repeat that setup for each independent config: filesystem, etc

You'll need a bunch of other plumbing to deal with callbacks and notify the REST clients when their configuration has been saved. Up to you whether to queue up calls or reject new calls if the queue is not empty.

Since you insist on not learning and using the awesome async.js library that will increase your fluency with asynchronous programming and teach you valuable things, here's the deal. Use this thing called a variable.

```
var updatingNetwork = false;
app.put('/api/config/network', function (req, res) {
   if (updatingNetwork) {
       return res.status(409).send("Try later");
   }
   updatingNetwork = true;
   updateNetworkConfig(req.body.config, function (error) {
       updatingNetwork = false;
       if (error) {
           return res.status(500).send(error);
       }
       res.status(200).send("done");
   });   
});
```

- When a request comes in, if `updatingNetwork` is true, you know there's already an update in process, either queue this one up or reject it.

Comment: this is a good answer on how I could do it with async.js, but what methods could I apply to solve this without async.js or another library?